# Angular 4 Deeper Databind

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a request from database, and the response is an object, what is included much more data 
The response result is the next:

```
ID:{} CATEGORY:{} USERNAME:{} etc...
```

I've got more CATEGORY TYPE ( user, superuser, analyst, etc... )
I would like to bind the category as like a normal bind. So I don't want to write all category type it individually, I want to bind it.

**NOW my code looks like this:**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data ">
   <div *ngIf="data.category === 'analyst'">
      <mat-list>
      </mat-list>     
   </div>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let data of data.data ">
    <div *ngIf="data.category === 'user'">
        <mat-list>
        </mat-list>     
    </div>
</div>
```

**I would like to display data for users on the next way.**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data ">
   <div *ngIf="data.category === '{{data.category}}'">
      <mat-list>
      </mat-list>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to llok at the ngSwitch statement?

Comment: Are you trying to reference the 'category' property from your iterator's parent object data ?

Comment: Yes I think I would like to that.

Comment: Group your datasource by category then iterate the groups.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to access the property, 'category' from the object, *data*, which contains your iterator *data* for comparison.

In that case, you should probably use a different variable name for you iteration and it should be just fine; like,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.data ">
    <div *ngIf="item.category === data.category">
        <mat-list>
        </mat-list>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is :

1. Iterate your data list
2. Push `data.catgory` in some array
3. Read that array in HTML as:

   `<div *ngFor = "let item in newArr">
       <mat-list>
           </mat-list> 
    </div>`